# My subdivision modifier seems to be capped at 2

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm adding a cube to my scene and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to subdivide it 4 times. However, it only subdivides it 2 times (Blender 3.5 and 3.6). After some experimentation, I have discovered that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> both work as they should, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> seem to be capped at 2 subdivisions.

[image: Sub division levels 1 - 4 on a simple cube]

Also, if I apply the modifiers, they only subdivide to level 2. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Check this: Go to Render properties > Simplify and see if is selected, if so, turn it off. If not that, we might need more infor

Comment: Wow! That was exactly the problem! I was crawling through my prefrencesand trying to toggle every  setting that seemed like it might help. I did what you recommended and it works great! Thaank you @Emir ! If you want,  please add that as  your answer and I will mark it accordingly! You're awesome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have Simplify ON.

Go to Render properties > Simplify and turn it off

[image]