# I have question about Subdivision surface modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have Subdivision surface modifier error
Raising the level further from 1 caused an error that no longer made a difference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My subdiv modifier seems to be capped at 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299791/my-subdiv-modifier-seems-to-be-capped-at-2)

Comment: Hello, Milia, since it's been a while now, I'll assume that the linked answer is a duplicate, and this can be fairly closed. If not , please edit to explain why, and we can re-open your post.